# window load function loads images fully?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
// executes when complete page is fully loaded, 
//including all frames, objects and images 
}
```

What does it mean "images"? Does it mean both the "background images set in css" and "images set in document through img tag"?

Comment: .load will wait until your browser start downloading all files. Does means that all resources will be ready in the DOM. If the background images are necessary for the current page, they will also be downloaded, and you will be also capale to manipulate css background property from jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

[GlobalEventHandlers.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

This includes css background images, if they are part of the current DOM.

To safely execute Javascript code to manipulate DOM elements it is not necessary to wait for the entire page to be loaded. You can use `$(document).ready()` which will only run once the DOM is ready, but will not in any case include images, iframes, scripts and stylesheets.

[Here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) you can find some more information on that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation David. When do we need a preloader? Do we need it actually?

Comment: This is up to you if you want to add a preloader. You don't have to, just make sure not do manipulate anything inside the DOM before it is not fully loaded. To execute Javascript code safely on page elements you can use the `$(document).ready()` method. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/